# How to prevent a custom view passing touch events to parent viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, custom-view

I have a couple of custom views in a `viewpager` and I find the `viewpager's` `ontouch` event will conflict with the `ontouchevent` of the custom view which will result in that I can not drag the custom view around as expected. To resolve this problem I try to set the `ontouchevent` of the custom view to return true but the `touchevent` of `viewpager` still gets triggered. How Can I prevent the `viewpager` from being processing `ontouchevent`? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ViewPager uses  `onInterceptTouchEvent()` to get the touches before its children. Take a look at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html) and overwrite `onInterceptTouchEvent()` of the Pager as you like.

> The onInterceptTouchEvent() method is called whenever a touch event is detected on the surface of a ViewGroup, including on the surface of its children. If onInterceptTouchEvent() returns true, the MotionEvent is intercepted, meaning it will be not be passed on to the child, but rather to the onTouchEvent() method of the parent.

Comment: From your description, it looks like if onInterceptTouchEvent() returns true the children of the view pager will not respond to touch events as well and onInterceptTouchEvent does not have a listener to override like onTouchEvent does.

Comment: You have to create a subclass of the Viewpager. There is no Listener like in onTouch, cause it is usually not a good idea to prevent the pager from paging. Check out the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/79398eaefea45e61d839cf4e0534f0eafee70a09/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java) of the Viewpager for more details what is happening in onInterceptTouch.